# What's the difference between DDR3 PC3-1300, PC3-1600, PC3-12800, etc

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, ddr3

My mainboard has only 2 slots for RAM. Currently, Speccy says that I have:

```
2 x Kingston 4GB DD3 PC3-10700
```

Can I replace these RAMs with `2 x 8GB DD3 PC3-12800`

My mainboard is a Gigabyte GA-H61M-DS2 Rev 2.0 and on it's specs it says:

```
 1. 2 x 1.5V DDR3 DIMM sockets supporting up to 16 GB of system memory
    * Due to Windows 32-bit operating system limitation, when more than 4 GB of physical memory is installed, the actual memory size displayed will be less than 4 GB.
 2. Dual channel memory architecture
 3. Support for DDR3 2200(OC)/1333/1066/800 MHz memory modules
 4. Support for non-ECC memory modules
```

Comment: What frequency is your current memory running at?  What frequency is the memory you want to use going to run at?  A quick search indicates that PC3-12800 would run at 1600 MHz, which your motherboard, does not specifically support.  So you would have to select a SPD/XMP profile that forces the memory to run at a compatible speed.  Once you research these questions, update your question, and I will answer your question.

Comment: Currently my RAM runs at 2x 667 Mhz according to Speccy.

Comment: You answered one of my questions but didn't edit your question so it includes the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PC3-12800 (12800 MB/sec) is the same thing as DDR3 1600MHz (1600 MHz data transfer rate) and it runs at 800 MHz DDR clock. Similarly for others, just divide/multiply by 8.

Any memory that has the correct voltage and capacity and is same or faster than what is supported by the board should work in the board. The memory will run at 1333 MHz (PC3-10700), unless you enable overclocking (XMP or other) on the board because the CPU likely doesn't support 1600 MHz within its specification.

So in your case, there should be no issue replacing your RAMs with the new pair. I say should as there can always be incompatibilies beyond what is covered by specification.

Answer (score -1):

> My mainboard has only 2 slots for RAM. Currently, Speccy says that I have:
>
> 2 x Kingston 4GB DD3 PC3-10700
> Can I replace these RAMs with 2 x 8GB DD3 PC3-12800
>
> My mainboard is a Gigabyte GA-H61M-DS2 Rev 2.0 and on its specs it says:
>
> 1. 2 x 1.5V DDR3 DIMM sockets supporting up to 16 GB of system memory
>
>    - Due to Windows 32-bit operating system limitation, when more than 4 GB of >physical memory is installed, the actual memory size displayed will be less than 4 >GB.
> 2. Dual-channel memory architecture
> 3. Support for DDR3 2200(OC)/1333/1066/800 MHz memory modules
> 4. Support for non-ECC memory modules

As per your motherboard, it only supports RAM with DDR3 1333 Mhz/PC3-10700
PC3-12800 has 1600 Mhz FSB. You'll encounter system blue screen when using Windows OS.